# ImportError: cannot import name 'zip' from 'itertools' (unknown location)

Tags: python

I have a problem with importing zip method. ImportError: cannot import name 'zip' from 'itertools' (unknown location). I have already installed more-itertools with pip. Could someone help me? I'm using Python 3.7.9.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from itertools import zip
```

Comment: There is no `zip` in `itertools`. `zip` is a built-in function. Or did you mean `zip_longest`?

Comment: I am looking for an equivalent for izip but it is on 2.x version

Comment: Built-in `zip` in Python 3 does the same job as `itertools.izip` in 2.x. So you don't need to import anything.